# Encrypted Vegetables

Tags: rebus, emoji

Similar to the last puzzle, figure out the vegetables:

> 1. A  a->an,n->? $\boxed{8}-\tau$
> 2. Bag->Cab() 2021-1980
> 3. $(TO)_2+F$
> 4. ⛽ K out$\times$ ??
> 5. ️ I $\boxed{6}$ $F=kx$
> 6. 
> 7. 
> 8. $90$deg=$\frac \pi 2$? -$\boxed9$
> 9. iP
> 10. 
> 11. $\boxed{11}$-(v+1) +$Cu_2$
> 12. Negative-a+0
> 13. $£20237+\boxed{£7500}\leftarrow$
> 14. 
> 15. $\boxed{^{27}}$  A,an,?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Community Wiki answer to try and get all of them between us...

1. A  a->an,n->? $\boxed{8}-\tau$

> **ASPARAGUS** = A + SPAR + A (since 'a' is the article that precedes a word beginning with 'n', much as 'an' precedes a word beginning with 'a') + (-au)GUS(-t) (removing 'tau') (@Stiv)

2. Bag->Cab() 2021-1980

> Suspect this is **CABBAGE** but it seems overclued? BAGGAGE with Bag->Cab seems (almost) sufficient without the additional AGE calculation at the end...? (@Stiv)

3. $(TO)_2+F$

> **TOMATO** = TO + MA (Newton's Second Law) + TO (@Stiv)

4. ⛽ K out$\times$ ??

> **PUMPKIN** = PUMP + K + IN (opposite of 'out') (@Stiv)

5. ️ I $\boxed{6}$ $F=kx$

> **ARTICHOKE** = ART + I + C (Carbon = element#6) + [HOOKE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law) (@Stiv)

6. 

> Possibly **SPINACH** = SPIN + ACHE (if we interpret the woman holding her stomach as being in pain rather than pregnant?) (@Stiv)

7. 

> **CHILLI** = Homophone of 'chilly' (@Stiv)

8. $90$deg=$\frac \pi 2$? -$\boxed9$

> **RADISH** = [RAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) + (-f)ISH (Fluorine = element#9) (@Stiv)

9. iP

> **TURNIP** = TURN + IP (@Stiv)

10. 

> **EGGPLANT** = EGG + PLANT (@Stiv)

11. $\boxed{11}$-(v+1) +$Cu_2$

> **CUCUMBER** = CU + CU + (-nove)MBER (removing 'v' + 'one') (@Stiv)

12. Negative-a+0

> **ONION** = O + (-a)NION (@Stiv)

13. $£20237+\boxed{£7500}\leftarrow$

> *Not yet solved.*

14. 

> **GINGER** = GIN + GER(many) (@Stiv)

15. $\boxed{^{27}}$  A,an,?

> Possibly **CORN** = **Co**balt + **r**a**n** with the A, an, saying to remove the vowel? (@SteveV)

Comment: Could 15 be rot13(Pbhetrggr=Pb(onyg, ryrzrag 27)+hetr+???)?

Comment: @trolley813 Not sure - I also considered rot13(pbevnaqre = Pb + Ena + Qre (Trezna cersvk)) even though that's really a herb rather than a vegetable. Then again we've got a couple of fruits (technically) on this list anyway, so who's to say?!

Comment: I've considered that too, so yes, it's probably still unclear.

Comment: As for 13, my only thought was (Orrgebbg=Ovg(pbva, £20237 vf arneyl 0.5 OGP, v.r.unys bs ovgpbva)+???).

Comment: @00xxqhxx00 Aha, I see the wordplay for 1 now, thanks. Re the to-veg-or-not-to-veg debate, I was just referring to things like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato#Fruit_versus_vegetable), which holds for #11 too - not a criticism, just a remark that perhaps we need to cast our net more widely for some of these :)